# Verify authorization to third party

Tags: twitter, oauth

Is it possible to verify to third parties, that a user has given authorization to an app?

As a fallback, the third party could send a challenge token to the app, which would then be tweeted by it, thus demonstrating it has authorization. But ideally it wouldn't have to pollute the twitter stream.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of tweeting, the challenge would be to follow, then DM a message? At least that's not public?